# Want to split screen vertically in two portions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider that have controls on right and left side. I did not show that controls and hide there visibilty with css. I want to divide my screen into two vertical portions right and left.

Then I want to link the right portion with right slider button, so when the user brings the mouse on right half portion of screen, they can click anywhere on the right portion to change the slide - and the same for left.

Anybody have idea where to start, suggestion, or code snippets?

Comment: Share your slider code! then can anyone help you out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort out it by using css and then use the slick method to control the navigation of slick.

Here are the method that you can use .

```
slickGoTo
int : slide number, boolean: should animate
Navigates to a slide by index
slickNext
none
Navigates to the next slide
slickPrev
none
Navigates to the previous slide
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slider{
position:relative;
    background:#F00;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
}
.left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:#CCC;
    left:0px;
    z-index:2;
 
}
.right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
     <div class="right">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: For reference you can check this. this is horizontal and i want this vertical.  http://mirkoborsche.com/2015-ZeitMagazin_14-19

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/maheswaran/0pzm9v1h/ you need like this... because your url not open

Comment: http://mirkoborsche.com/2015-ZeitMagazin_14-19      you can check this link is working fine and the demo you put here is not what want. if you can check this link then you have better idea . Thanks :)